# MySQL Server Error

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-2003

I continue to have problems with getting my 5.6.13 version of mysql going with the following error msg. :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\mysql-5.6.13-winx64\bin>mysql
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost'(10061)
```

and incidentally I put the "bin" folder into my PATH env. variable but still failed to connect to MySQL. Can someone help me please?

Comment: Sounds like the server isn't running.

Comment: See [`Can't connect to [local] MySQL server`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, server (mysqld) dose not run.

"mysql" is client.